# Colors not being set correctly via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, internet-explorer-7

As per suggestion from a user, I decided to redo my question.

What I'm trying to do is change foreground and background colors of several elements without using a stylesheet.

Next to each colourIt call just under the script tag is the style I'm trying to reproduce Javascript style. This is because my stylesheet is too large and is taking up more than 1/2 my website code, especially with all those background color declarations.

This is my new code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ID="CELL">
      GREENonYELLOW
      <p>BLUEonRED<i>REDonGREEN<b>YELLOWonBLUE</b>REDonGREEN</i>BLUEonRED</p>
      <p>BLUEonRED<i>REDonGREEN<b>YELLOWonBLUE</b>REDonGREEN</i>BLUEonRED</p>
      GREENonYELLOW
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>

colorIt('CELL','','#FF0','#0F0');      //#CELL {background:#F00;color:#0F0}
colorIt('CELL','P','#F00','#00F');     //#CELL P{background:#00F;color:#F00}
colorIt('CELL','P I','#0F0','#F00');   //#CELL P I{background:#F00;color:#0F0}
colorIt('CELL','P I B','#00F','#FF0'); //#CELL P I B{background:#FF0;color:#00F}

//populate array with pointers as parents to the children are found
function getKidValues(parent,children){
  var allKids=[],childrenSet=document.getElementsByTagName(children);
  childrenSetSize=childrenSet.length;
  for(kidsIndex=0;kidsIndex < childrenSetSize;kidsIndex++){
    if(childrenSet[kidsIndex].parentNode==parent){
      allKids.push(childrenSet[kidsIndex])
    }
  }
  return allKids;
}

function colorIt(parent,kids,backgroundColor,foregroundColor){
  if(parent){
    parentPtr=document.getElementById(parent);
    if(kids){
      kidSet=kids.split(' ');
      kidSetSize=kids.length;
      for (index=0;index < kidSetSize;index++){
        //get proper kids. I think I need to pass new parameters but idk which??
        currentKids=getKidValues(parentPtr,kidSet[index]);
        //go through the kids setting the colors.
        for (thisKidIndex in currentKids){
          setColor(currentKids[thisKidIndex],backgroundColor,foregroundColor);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//just sets color of element: This function isn't problematic.
function setColor(item,back,fore){
  if(item){
    item=item.style;
    if(item){
      if(back){item.backgroundColor=back}
      if(fore){item.color=fore}
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

I feel I need to add recursion to solve this, but if there's another way to solve it without killing a computer processor and that works in Internet Explorer 7, then I'm looking forward to that answer.

So far, this javascript was only able to satisfy one child to the ColorIt function correctly, It does not work with more than one child.

What can I do to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I changed my javascript code to:

```
function setValues(parent,children,depth,b,f){
  var childrenSet=document.getElementsByTagName(children[depth]),childrenSetSize=childrenSet.length;
  for(kidsIndex=0;kidsIndex < childrenSetSize;kidsIndex++){
    var m=childrenSet[kidsIndex];
    if(m.parentNode==parent){
      if ((depth+1) < children.length){
        setValues(m,children,depth+1,b,f);
      }else{
        setColor(m,b,f);
      }
    }
  }
}

function colorIt(parent,kids,backgroundColor,foregroundColor){
  if(parent){
    parentPtr=document.getElementById(parent);
    if(kids){
      kidSet=kids.split(' ');
      setValues(parentPtr,kidSet,0,backgroundColor,foregroundColor);
    }
  }
}

function setColor(item,back,fore){
  if(item){
    item=item.style;
    if(item){
      if(back){item.backgroundColor=back}
      if(fore){item.color=fore}
    }
  }
}
```

and everything works but only the first line of text is being affected. I want both lines to be the same way, not one being just one color. Remember, I'm trying to rewrite some of my CSS. see above.

Comment: Internet Explorer 7??? Why?

Comment: Because I'm monetizing my site with adsense and according to my server logs, a few people are using older browsers such as IE 7 and even IE 6.